# couchDB queries

Tags: view, dictionary, couchdb

I am a couchDB noob and am having no luck getting a filtered response from my views.  No matter the query I always get the whole view, and this makes no sense.

For example in a users database... I tried this map function, just to get a feel for how it works.

```
    login: {
        map: function(doc){
            if (doc.firstName && doc.lastName)
                emit(doc.firstName, doc.lastName);
        }
    }
```

Text book stuff right?

But when I POST a query that looks like this...

```
    {key: ["Mo"]} ... or ... {key:"Mo"}
```

I get back everything... the whole view!  Even this...

```
    {startkey:["Mo"], endkey:["Mo"]} ... or ... {startkey:"Mo", endkey:"Mo"}
```

Encoding the query into the url and doing a GET gives me the same response!!

What do I do to make this work?  What's the special sauce?  Do I need to sacrifice an animal?  Or am I just not relaxing hard enough?

Comment: You should read [the docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API), none of your examples is a couchdb query. Where have you found that, e.g., `{startkey:"mo", endkey:"Mo"}` is a valid query?

Comment: The docs show an example of a "keys" query in json, right on that very page, so I figured that all queries could be done this way, which makes sense, otherwise people would need to send passwords and other sensitive data in querystrings... and that's just terrible security wise... or am I wrong?

Comment: You can't use a POST for querying a view, with exception to asking for multiple document keys via `{"keys": []}`. You need to use GET with querystring arguments. Plus, CouchDB has [built-in authentication](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html), so you shouldn't be using a view to handle logins anyways. What URL are you using specifically anyways?

Comment: POST is not securer than GET, you [need HTTPS](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_enable_SSL) for that. Regarding queries, the page says "[The following URL query arguments for GET/HEAD requests are allowed](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options)", then you cant use POST. The only exception I know of is `keys` (note the `s`) as documented on the same page. Then, querying for a range of keys, is done appending `?startkey=KEY1&endkey=KEY2`. HTH

Answer (score 0):

So, just to be clear, your URL should look like this:

```
http://your.server/your_db/_design/view_id/_view/view_name?key="Mo"
```

And most browsers will encode those `"`s correctly into `%22`s